# Flex pass data between views from a list item

Tags: php, database, apache-flex, list, view

Hi everyone first of all thanks for your attention and support. I'm a beginner in the flex world... what I want to do is probably too easy but I can't figure it out.

I'm practicing a simple mobile application that makes use of database made it in phpmyadmin and connected to my mobile project. What I want to do is: when i click in any of my list items, this one pops up the next view showing the values of the selected item in all the text inputs from the database table. I know how to display it in the view that I'm implementing the list, but I get an error because I don't have (and don't want to) a list item in my other view:

```
protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            titleTextInput.text = list.selectedItem.title;
            dateIntro.selectedDate = list.selectedItem.date;
            photoTextInput.text = list.selectedItem.photo;
            descriptionTextInput.text = list.selectedItem.description;
        }
```

But what I need to do to get the same result in my other view?

The project has 2 views,

this is the first view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
    xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*"
    xmlns:detallesservice="services.detallesservice.*" add="home(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.events.FlexEvent;

        import spark.events.IndexChangeEvent;
        protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var detalles2:Detalles = new Detalles();
            detalles2.title = titleTextInput.text;
            detalles2.date = dateIntro.selectedDate;
            detalles2.photo = photoTextInput.text;
            detalles2.description = descriptionTextInput.text;

            detallesService.createDetalles(detalles2);
            detallesService.getAllDetalles();
        }

        protected function list_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            getAllDetallesResult2.token = detallesService.getAllDetalles();
        }


        protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            detallesService.deleteDetalles(list.selectedItem.title);
        }

        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            titleTextInput.text = list.selectedItem.title;
            dateIntro.selectedDate = list.selectedItem.date;
            photoTextInput.text = list.selectedItem.photo;
            descriptionTextInput.text = list.selectedItem.description;

            navigator.pushView(asyouwishView, list.selectedItem);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <valueObjects:Detalles id="detalles"/>
    <detallesservice:DetallesService id="detallesService"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="createDetallesResult"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="getAllDetallesResult2"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="deleteDetallesResult"/>
</fx:Declarations>
<s:List id="list" x="1100" y="142" width="716" height="372"
        creationComplete="list_creationCompleteHandler(event)" labelField="title" change="list_changeHandler(event)">
    <s:AsyncListView list="{getAllDetallesResult2.lastResult}"/>
</s:List>
<s:Form defaultButton="{button}">
    <s:FormItem label="Title">
        <s:TextInput id="titleTextInput" text="{detalles.title}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem width="800" label="Date">
        <s:DateSpinner id="dateIntro" displayMode="date" selectedDate="{detalles.date}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Photo">
        <s:TextInput id="photoTextInput" text="{detalles.photo}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Description">
        <s:TextInput id="descriptionTextInput" text="{detalles.description}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:Button id="button" label="CreateDetalles" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Form>
<s:Form x="18" y="950">
    <s:FormItem label="CreateDetalles">
        <s:TextInput id="createDetallesTextInput"
                     text="{createDetallesResult.lastResult as String}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
</s:Form>
<s:Button id="myDelete" x="1100" y="558" label="Delete" click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>
```

this is the second view:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import spark.events.ViewNavigatorEvent;
        protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // Please uncomment the below line if Data Management is enabled for Detalles and updateDetalles is used as the create function.
            // var detalles:Detalles = new Detalles();
            detalles.title = titleTextInput.text;
            detalles.date = dateIntro.selectedDate;
            detalles.photo = photoTextInput.text;
            detalles.description = descriptionTextInput.text;

            updateDetallesResult.token = detallesService.updateDetalles(detalles);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <valueObjects:Detalles id="detalles"/>
    <detallesservice:DetallesService id="detallesService"/>
    <s:CallResponder id="updateDetallesResult"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:actionContent>
    <s:Button label="BACK" click="{navigator.popView();}"/>
</s:actionContent>

<s:Form x="70" y="68" defaultButton="{button}">
    <s:FormItem label="Title">
        <s:TextInput id="titleTextInput" text="@{detalles.title}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem width="766" label="Date">
        <s:DateSpinner id="dateIntro" displayMode="date" selectedDate="@{detalles.date}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Photo">
        <s:TextInput id="photoTextInput" text="@{detalles.photo}" />
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:FormItem label="Description">
        <s:TextInput id="descriptionTextInput" text="@{detalles.description}"/>
    </s:FormItem>
    <s:Button id="button" label="UpdateDetalles" click="button_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn and use framework is necessary.I recommend [Swizframework](http://swizframework.org).

Data binding and events in Swiz is a breeze. You'll love it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion =) I'll try it, do you know a better way to learn how to use it?

Comment: Just use it make something, it's the best way to learn something new.